# Load the keys used to register this device

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to load a manual key pair:

```
KeyPair keys = String 
               "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
                +"MHQCAQEEIDzESrZFmTaOozu2NyiS8LMZGqkHfpSOoI/qA9Lw+d4NoAcGBSuBBAAK\n"
                +"oUQDQgAE7kIqoSQzC/UUXdFdQ9Xvu1Lri7pFfd7xDbQWhSqHaDtj+XY36Z1Cznun\n"
                +"GDxlA0AavdVDuoGXxNQPIed3FxPE3Q==\n"+
               "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

To connect to Google IoT core from an Android App.

When I search, I only find project android things auto create Keypair.
Not load manual Ec_private string to KeyPair

Comment: You should get a new private key and not use the one you posted here.

Comment: You may check the [Provisioning credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/device-security#provisioning_credentials) sub-chapter of the "Device security" documentation page for related instructions.